# How to find the xpath for this?

Tags: xpath

For below code:

```
<a href="profile?action=edit" class="btn btn-embossed btn-primary mtl pull-right"> Edit Details</a>
```

I am arriving this xpath: ("//a[@href='profile?action=edit'")

it says invalid xpath.

Can any one let me know pls?

Thanks

Comment: You forgot to close your square brackets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
//a[@href='profile?action=edit']
```